# I want to take svn checkout of repository on my laptop remotely

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I have repository that  is created using Visual Svn server in my office and i want to take svn checkout at my home laptop.
I tried giving  http://hostname/svn/svn_repo_name in the url while taking
svn checkout

But it gives error saying "Unable to connect to repository at the url, No Such host  is known”.

Hostname is created in hostfile. Is there any other configuration needed.

I have also tried the steps mentioned in the below url
http://aleemansari.blogspot.com/2015/02/setup-apache-svn-with-wamp-on-windows.html

But after i restart wamp, it does not work and color of wamp icon is orange,it does not turn green

Please need your help.

Comment: Is your office's SVN server accessible from outside the company network? My guess is that it's not - most companies do not expose their internal source code repositories to the internet. You need to connect to your company network via a VPN and *then* attempt to check out.

Comment: Thanks alroc, will check for VPN

Answer (score 1):

Like **alroc** already mentioned, you probably just can't access your company's network.
Make sure you can connect by opening cmd and writing:

```
ping hostname
```

If you are able to ping the host, then the the protocol of the server is configured to something different from "http".
try:

```
https://hostname/svn/svn_repo_name
```

or

```
svn://hostname/svn/svn_repo_name
```

or

```
svn+ssh://hostname/svn/svn_repo_name
```

edit: ***Basic*** mentioned, `ping` command might not always work, so it's not a reliable method for checking connectivity to the server. Anyway, you should be able to connect through one of the protocols if the server IS reachable

Comment: Note that some servers and routers specifically ignore pings as a security mechanism, so it's not completely reliable for testing connectivity.

Comment: Thanks Alex, but i am not able to ping the hostname, it gives the message Request timed out

Comment: VisualSVN Server does not support svn or svn+ssh access. The server supports HTTP(S) only. Therefore, the two URL examples are irrelevant here.

Comment: @bahrep It's probably irrelevant, but you can still set up svn server to use the svn protocol with VisualSVN as it contains svnserve. It is probably not the case, but you never know.

Comment: @AlexWeitz it contains, but setting up `svnserve` is strongly discouraged and is not supported. `svnserve` should be used only in certain cases, but not for regular user access.

Comment: @bahrep I agree, my point is, it is better to cover that possibility as well. You can have VisualSVN installed on a server and not use it.